# Как заполнить шаблон?

Tags: silverlight

У меня есть шаблон сайта на Silverlight. В SilverLight я не силен. Но мне нужно сделать небольшой сайт с помощью данного шаблона. Вот что именно меня интересует.

1. Как заполнить существующие страницы в шаблоне отформатированным текстом, картинками и т.д.?
2. Как добавить новые страницы, не нарушая структуры и дизайн сайта?

Answer (score 1):

Кидаете файл в проект вместе с другими в проекте (перетащите его на проект).

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="здесь твой файл.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Это пишете перед

```
<grid>
<!-- сама программа -->
</grid>
```